# What java comet-style framework is the most mature and robust?

Tags: java, jetty, comet, tomcat6, long-polling

There seems to be significant issues with Tomcat6/Comet/NIO ([example](http://bill.burkecentral.com/2008/11/12/buggybroken-tomcat-6-comet-nio-apis)). Are the majority of people doing asynchronous http using something else?  Jetty/continuations? What about Glassfish's servlet 3.0 implementation?  Others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say [atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) - it uses the best underlying technology available - be it servlet 3.0, jetty, etc. (I haven't used it, though, but it was my choice when I was about to)

Comment: I agree, atmosphere is very well done.  However, what backing comet API is the most robust?  In other words, what platform would you prefer to deploy your atmosphere application on?